# Keyboard Unresponsive

Tags: python, pygame

I can't seem to find out why my keyboard work. I have tried changing the speed, changing the class, and swapped it out for using the mouse but I want more keyboard! No errors appear when I run it but the main player just stays in the top left and doesn't move. I've also duplicated this code with less bonus characters and it worked but once I add bonus and more levels, it fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The link is for all the images and code.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/162vsO20kRoNBy6IJa3WgSq4D5ZB5PsI2?usp=sharing

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
pygame.init()

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("aboriginal.png")

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        # -- Attributes
        # Set speed vector
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changeSpeed(self, x, y):
        """ Change the speed of the player"""
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        """ Find a new position for the player"""
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y


class Bonus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, pic):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(pic)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 700
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption(('Outback Steakhouse'))
background = pygame.image.load('winter.png')
background2 = pygame.image.load('timthumb.jpg')
background3 = pygame.image.load('winter.png')
background4 = pygame.image.load('timthumb.jpg')
background5 = pygame.image.load('rugbyStadium.png')

# sprites
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bonus_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(10):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Create a player instance
player = Player(0,0)
all_sprites_list.add(player)

# Bonus instance
kiwi = Bonus('kiwi.png')
kiwi.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
kiwi.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
bonus_list.add(kiwi)
all_sprites_list.add(kiwi)

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

score = 0

level = 1

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

            # Set the speed based on the key pressed
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changeSpeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changeSpeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changeSpeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changeSpeed(0, 3)

        # Reset speed when key goes up
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changeSpeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changeSpeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changeSpeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changeSpeed(0, -3)

    # See if the player block has collided with anything including bonus
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)
    bonus_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bonus_list, True)

    # Check the list of collisions.
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score += 1
        print(score)
    for bonus in bonus_hit_list:
        score += 10
        print(score)

    # Check to see if all the blocks are gone.
    # If they are, level up.
    if len(block_list) == 0 and len(bonus_list) == 0:
        # Add one to the level
        level += 1

        # Add more blocks. How many depends on the level.
        # Also, an 'if' statement could be used to change what
        # happens customized to levels 2, 3, 4, etc.
        for i in range(level * 10):
            # This represents a block
            block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)

            # Set a random location for the block
            block.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
            block.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

            # Add the block to the list of objects
            block_list.add(block)
            all_sprites_list.add(block)

        for i in range(level):
            if level == 1:
                kiwi = Bonus('kiwi.png')
                kiwi.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
                kiwi.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
                bonus_list.add(kiwi)
                all_sprites_list.add(kiwi)
            if level == 2:
                koala = Bonus('koala.png')
                koala.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
                koala.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
                bonus_list.add(koala)
                all_sprites_list.add(koala)
            if level == 3:
                kangaroo = Bonus('kangaroo.png')
                kangaroo.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
                kangaroo.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
                bonus_list.add(kangaroo)
                all_sprites_list.add(kangaroo)
            if level == 4:
                boomerang = Bonus('boomerang.png')
                boomerang.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
                boomerang.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
                bonus_list.add(boomerang)
                all_sprites_list.add(boomerang)
            if level == 5:
                rugby = Bonus('rugby.png')
                rugby.rect.x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH - 64)
                rugby.rect.y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 64)
                bonus_list.add(rugby)
                all_sprites_list.add(rugby)



    # ALL GAME LOGIC SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

    # Clear the screen and add new images
    if level == 1:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        message = font.render("Easy Peasy" , True, RED)
        screen.blit(message, [300, 10])
    elif level == 2:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background2, (0, 0))
    elif level == 3:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background3, (0, 0))
    elif level == 4:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background4, (0, 0))
    elif level == 5:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background5, (0,0))
    else:
        pygame.quit()

    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(text, [10, 10])

    text = font.render("Level: " + str(level), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(text, [10, 40])

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Change it back to a version that works, add one thing at a time until it stops working.  The thing you just added is where you went wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player doesn't move because you don't call the `update` method in the application loop:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    player.update()
```

Comment: Thank you, Rabbid! That did it. I had the method in there but never called it.